# I get “#VALUE!” as the result of `Evaluate` of user defined formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I get `"#VALUE!"` as the result of evaluate method in cell "C2". 
This is while the formula itself works fine if I use it as a worksheet formula in the cell rather than using it in VBA!

What am I doing wrong here?

**Note**: I am using office 2016.

```
Sub Evaluate_Method()

 Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
     
 ws.Range("C2").Formula = "=TRIM(ConcRange(A1:A1000))"   'this works correctly
    
 ws.Range("C2").Value = Evaluate(Trim(ConcRange(ws.Range("A1:A1000")))) 'I got "#VALUE!" on "C2"
     
End Sub

Function ConcRange(rng As Range, Optional Delim As String = ",")
     
    Dim cel As Range
     
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If Trim(cel) <> "" Then
           ConcRange = CStr(ConcRange) & Delim & CStr(Trim(cel.Value))
        End If
    Next cel
     
   If Len(ConcRange) > 0 Then
     ConcRange = Right(ConcRange, Len(ConcRange) - 1)
   End If
     
End Function
```

Comment: Please,  use `ws.Range("C2").Value = Evaluate("Trim(ConcRange(" & ws.Range("A1:A1000").address & "))")`. You cannot evaluate a range in that way. You need the range address, as you use it in the above formula...

Comment: I tried supplying a general answer, not dependent of the range address. With the above way, you can use it **as it is** for any range. You should only declare and `Set` the respective range (`rgn`). Of course, using it as `ws.Range("C2").Value = Evaluate("Trim(ConcRange(" & rng.address & "))")`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Evaluate Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) allows you to get the result of a worksheet-style formula from within VBA.

It has to be enclosed in quotation marks so a first cut at it might be

```
ws.Range("C2").Value = Evaluate("Trim(ConcRange(ws.Range(""A1:A1000"")))")
```

However this still doesn't work because it's mixing a VBA expression `ws.Range(""A1:A1000"")` which yields an object with an enclosing string.

It should be

```
ws.Range("C2").Value = Evaluate("=TRIM(ConcRange(A1:A1000))")
```

or

```
ws.Range("C2").Value = [=TRIM(ConcRange(A1:A1000))]
```

like you had for the formula version.

Comment: `ws.Evaluate` would be preferable to the default `Application.Evaluate`, which uses the ActiveSheet as the context for the formula.